# Solving nonlinear system for a scalar when the equation has an inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

Suppose $f(\alpha) = \log \det[({\bf A} - \alpha {\bf B})({\bf A} - \alpha {\bf B})^\top] + \alpha c$, where ${\bf A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m < n$. I want to find the value of $\alpha$ where the gradient of $f$ is zero. I can use general purpose optimization routine implemented in a software to find the value of $\alpha$. However, I am thinking whether there is a closed form solution to this equation?

Define ${\bf X} = ({\bf A} - \alpha {\bf B})({\bf A} - \alpha {\bf B})^\top$
$$
f'(\alpha) = 2 \ \text{trace}({\bf X}^{-1}(\alpha {\bf BB}^\top - {\bf B A}^\top)) + c = 0
$$
I am not sure how to extract $\alpha$ from the inverse term.

Comment: if $\alpha$ is a scalar, it commutes with the matrix multiplication and the trace.

Comment: @user619894 That's true, but there is a $\alpha$ inside the inverse function.

Comment: maybe if $AA^T$ is invertible and $\alpha$ is small, you could try an expansion?

Comment: @user619894 $AA^\top$ is invertible, but I have no idea about the value of $\alpha$. Could you please explain what type of an expansion that you have suggested here?

Comment: $(X+\alpha Y +\alpha^2 Z)^{-1} = X^{-1} (I+\alpha Y X^{-1} +\alpha^2 Z X^{-1})^{-1}$ which can be expanded similarly to $(I+\alpha B)^{-1}\sim I-\alpha B + \cdots$